# 2dimension matrix interface for add() and copy()

Tags: java, interface

Trying to implements the interface functions. Having some issues.

1. For makeEmpty() function seems like i need to transverse the matrix but not sure what that means
2. For addition and copy function how should i do it

For the test class i havent write yet. Not very sure how to write
java class

```
public class Matrix implements MatrixInterface{
    private int [][] matrixArray;
    private int dimension;
    
    public Matrix(int n){
        matrixArray = new int[n][n];
        dimension = n;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void makeEmpty(int m) {
        //check dimension - conditional statement
        if(m > dimension){
            m = dimension;
        }
       
        //transverse the matrix rows and cols
        
        //loops = 2 loops
        for(int i=0; i<=m; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<=m; j++){
                matrixArray[i][j]=0;   // matrix at i row and j col =0
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean storeValue(int i, int j, int value) {
        for(int p=0; p<=i; p++){
            for(int q=0; q<=j; q++){
                matrixArray[p][q] = value;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix) {
        for (int i=0; i < dimension; i++){
            for (int j=0; j < dimension; j++ ){
                
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean copy(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix) {
       
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String outputStr = "";
        for(int i=0; i<dimension; ++i){
            for(int j=0; j<dimension; ++i){
                outputStr += String.format("%4d", matrixArray[i][j]);
            }
            outputStr += "\n";
        }
        
        return outputStr;
    }
    
}
```

java interface

is boolean type for add() and copy() correct?

```
public interface MatrixInterface {
    void makeEmpty(int m);
    boolean storeValue(int i, int j, int value) ;
    
    boolean add(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix);
    boolean copy(MatrixInterface anotherMatrix);
}
```

Comment: "transverse" is not a verb. I don't know where the text came from, but probably "traverse" was intended. Why do you think `add` and `copy` should return `boolean`? When would they return true, and when would they return false? If you write out in English what add and copy are meant to do (the end result, not the implementation), perhaps you'll see how to write them.